# how to read excel file in matlab 2012

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file with heterogeneous data and headers.I want to store this excel file as my input. I know in matlab 2014 I can use the following command: readtable but I do no know how I can do it in matlab 2012. appreciate if any body can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The xlsread function will allow you to import numeric and text data.

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename)
```

Comment: [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename), gives me separate matrix.I want the whole things in one matrix or table and the other thing is that it changed the value of my excel file. I mean it changed 883991900000
to 8.839919000000000e+11.could you please let me know how I can have the exact value.

Comment: Both those values are the same value, it is just how it is presented in Matlab. The "raw" variable should have both the numbers and the text in a cell array.